# Empty hostname (sethostname)

Tags: linux, hostname, system-calls

For some unrelated reason I want to set the hostname of a Linux machine to an empty string using the `sethostname` system call.

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    sethostname("", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

While this works in principle I am wondering whether a.) emtpy hostnames are compliant to both SUSv2 and POSIX.1 and b.) whether setting an empty hostname can lead to some negative ramifications I am not foreseeing at the moment?

Comment: Note that `sethostname()` itself is not a POSIX function.

Comment: **You should explain your reasons.** Why can't you use `sethostname("simon-pc", 0);`  or `sethostname("linux-pc", 0);` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch In the specific case, the hostname is logically coupled to a "station name" in some industrial protocol (Linux is running on an embedded device). The latter protocol demands being able to set the station name to an empty string in some specific situations when a factory reset over the protocol is triggered.

Comment: I suggest discussing with the industrial provider of the device or of the station. Then upgrade the firmware and the documentation to set the hostname to some non-empty, but documented, string. It could happen that some later Linux kernel would *require* a non-empty hostname. And empty hostnames are confusing to any human reading them. The protocol software might also be updated! A hostname like `UNKNOWN` or `UNSETHOSTNAME` is a lot more readable than an empty one.

Comment: We are working on the device ourselves and must adhere to the specification of said industrial protocol which demands (even in the latest protocol specification) to allow for empty station names. The coupling to the Linux hostname was a design decision taken by us before the requirement of empty station names became apparent.

Comment: Then change your firmware to transform the empty hostname to e.g. `EMPTYHOSTNAME` and document that `EMPTYHOSTNAME` is changed to an empty string at protocol level. Like X11 did for empty `DISPLAY`. I feel that abusing the kernel is a door for some important technical debt in a couple of years.

Comment: This could surely be done but would add additional complexity to the system. That's why I currently tend to sticking with an empty Linux hostname in the rare cases of a factory reset if this would not have major ramifications I am not foreseeing.
But I might be wrong. Thanks for your opinion!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, if Linux ever changes to require a non-empty hostname, just complain to Linus about breaking userspace-visible behaviour in a backwards-incompatible way, and watch the change get undone...

Comment: That said, I would look into decoupling the Linux hostname from the protocol station name, or at least making the hostnames something like `station-foobar`, where `foobar` is the resulting station name. Hard coupling between unrelated things is seldom a good idea, but hey, at least you didn't tie it to the _DNS name_. (Also, if someone ever needs run more than one "station" on the same Linux box, having the station name hard tied to the hostname will be an issue...)

Comment: Linux could prefer following POSIX standards.... And *they* do evolve!

Answer (score 3):

You might get confusing outputs from some programs, which might cause issues if another program tried to parse them.

E.g. on the system I tried, the output from `uname -a` turned into this:

```
Linux  2.6.42-amd64 #1 SMP ...
```

where the hostname should be in between the two spaces. If some program were to try to parse that in the way awk does by default, i.e. with consecutive spaces treated as one, they'd end up picking the wrong fields. Of course you'd use `uname -m` or whatever instead, instead of parsing `uname -a`, but the same would apply to other programs.

`rsyslog` circumvented that by replacing the empty string with a placeholder:

```
Jan 15 18:28:14 localhost-empty-hostname kernel: [32741563.144045]...
```

That shouldn't cause any issues, but isn't too pretty.

(Oh, and at least on Debian, the `hostname` command doesn't accept an empty hostname, so I guess someone there doesn't think that's a supported configuration. I'm kinda surprised the kernel does accept that, but it probably doesn't use it internally except for some outputs anyway.)